# Grails Render Template Different Controller/Path

Tags: grails, gsp

I have a template that exists under views/dashboard/_myTemplate.gsp and from the DashboardController I can simply call

```
render template:'myTemplate'
```

and all is well.  I have a need to render this template from a different controller but the render method doesn't allow you to specify a controller and I can't seem to figure out how to define the path at which the template exists for the render to work correctly.  Is this even possible?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You do it by controller name:

```
render(template:'/dashboard/myTemplate')
```

Comment: It helps-me a lot! And if your want to use a view from another controller, use: render view: '/fooController/barView'

Comment: technically this is not the controller name, it's the path to the template relative to the `views` directory.