# Grails test-app failing due to mocking controller (2.3.7)

Tags: unit-testing, grails, groovy

I am testing my controller and so I mock out other methods by using...

```
MyController controller = [updateSomething:{obj-> null}] as MyController
```

However, when I run with grails test-app I see.

> Unable to load template for uri [/myController2_g/_refreshArea.gsp]. Template not found.

When the template is actually located at `/myController/_refreshArea.gsp`. Running as a regular unit test seems to work fine.

**Update**

I did find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3160367/grails-render-template-different-controller-path) but I don't like that approach are there others?

Comment: Can you add the test class to the question?

Comment: What part would you like? It is fairly long but I get my controller from the method above